# The 'name' attribute is invalid - the value is invalid according to its datatype 'servicenametype' the enumeration constraint failedin dynamics ax

Tags: xml, web-services, axapta, x++

I have a group service to deploy in dynamics ax, but I had this error:

> Le port « EmployCVgrp » n'a pas pu être déployé.
>   Erreur :
>   c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ServiceGeneration\EmployeCVservice.cs(42,19) : error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EmployeCV' does not exist in the namespace 'Dynamics.Ax.Application' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

In the same time in the `oas.config` found an other error:

> the 'name' attribute is invalid - the value is invalid according to its datatype 'servicenametype' the enumeration constraint failed"

there's my code who is generated automaticlly:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceGroupBehavior" name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.EmployCVgrp">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://AOS_SERVICE_HOST/DynamicsAx/Services/EmployCVgrp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultServiceGroupBinding" name="DefaultServiceGroupEndPoint" contract="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.ServiceGroup" />
</service>
```

Comment: <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceGroupBehavior" name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.EmployCVgrp">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://AOS_SERVICE_HOST/DynamicsAx/Services/EmployCVgrp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultServiceGroupBinding" name="DefaultServiceGroupEndPoint" contract="Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Services.ServiceGroup" />
   </service>

Comment: Regarding the service you try to deploy, is it an AX class or a C# proxy you want to use in AX? Can you give more context on the technical elements? Is the CIL compilation OK?